# SpinBox view on Android

Tags: android, android-view

There is a `SpinBox` widget in most GUI desktop frameworks ([QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qspinbox.html) in QT for example). But I can't find a similar view on Android framework.

I know there is a [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker) on Android but it is not similar to `SpinBox`

I need a view like in the image below :

[image]

Or this

[image: spinbox widget]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no equivalent to this in the Android SDK. You might be able to find a suitable library, or else you can write your own.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your comment, I hope someone can suggest me an existing library. As a last solution, I'll try to write my own.

Comment: One of many that you can find: [link](https://github.com/kojofosu/Quantitizer)

Comment: @javdromero Thanks for the link, I'll try this one. but, I hope to find a simpler one than this, without any animation, like the first image provided in the post.

Comment: More: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/149